# Count values of MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have my MySQL database with the data below.

I want to count how many times did john paid.

```
ID NAME NUMBER COUNTRY STATUS 
----------------------------------
1  JOHN  021    USA    PAID
2  MIKE  022    CA     UNPAID
3  KENT  023    UK     NOT-OPEN
4  JOHN  021    USA    PAID
```

**My query**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER WHERE NUMBER = '021' OR NAME = 'JOHN' HAVING STATUS = 'PAID'
```

**But am getting this error:**

> Unknown column 'STATUS' in 'having clause'

Comment: You need a `Group By` before the `Having`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER WHERE (NUMBER = '021' OR NAME = 'JOHN') AND (STATUS = 'PAID')
```

Answer (score 1):

Having work on result  .. you have not the column STATUS in you resul

or you add to the WHERE clause  (and avoid the having)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM USER 
WHERE ( NUMBER = '021' OR NAME = 'JOHN' )
AND STATUS = 'PAID'
```

or you add  the column to select (but this require for mysql version > 5.6 a group by to fr default sql_mode  setting )

```
SELECT COUNT(*), STATUS  
FROM USER 
WHERE NUMBER = '021' OR NAME = 'JOHN' 
GROUP BY STATUS 

HAVING STATUS = 'PAID'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `HAVING` by `AND`

Also to make sure that you only get the count of this single user, you also need to put

```
(NUMBER = '021' AND NAME = 'JOHN')
```

Try this:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER WHERE (NUMBER = '021' AND NAME = 'JOHN') AND STATUS = 'PAID'
```